# Random chess game pairings - should I use permutations or combinations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, self-learning

> The chess clubs of two schools consist of, respectively, 8 and 9 players. Four members from each club are randomly chosen to participate in a contest between the two schools. The chosen players from one team are then randomly paired with those from the other team, and each pairing plays a game of chess. Suppose that Rebecca and her sister Elise are on the chess clubs at different schools.

```
What is the probability that

(a) Rebecca and Elise will be paired?
(b) Rebecca and Elise will be chosen to represent their schools but will not play each other?
(c) either Rebecca or Elise will be chosen to represent her school?
```

I have seen some online resources and tried solving this question, but have been unable to.

For part $(a)$, I get the required numerator by fixing Rebecca and Elise, then permuting the rest by $\binom{7}{3} \cdot \binom{8}{3} \cdot 3!$ and the denominator for total possible pairings as $\binom{8}{4} \cdot \binom{9}{4} \cdot 4!$. This returns $1/18$.

I don't know how to solve part (b) and (c). I tried the (Total ways - number of ways where both sisters are together) using: $\binom{8}{4}\cdot\binom{9}{4}\cdot4! - \binom{7}{3}\cdot\binom{8}{3}\cdot3!$ divided by the total $\binom{8}{4}\cdot\binom{9}{4}\cdot4!$ but is so different from the book.

I am also not sure if the solutions are wrong or the text book, or me. I only know permutation & combinations, and not aware of random variables, conditional probabilities, or bayes theorem, or other ways. I am not even sure if selecting with replacement (the one used in picking colored bals from urns) will be used here or not.
Very confused and helpless. So kindly help me with the way how I should approach this question. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see why you multiplied numerator and denominator by 3! and 4! in part a.  Order doesn't matter.

Comment: @madfdadfd The $3!$ and $4!$ represent the random pairings.

Comment: @madfdadfd Since they had to be paired. 4! cause both groups can be matched in 4*3*2*1 ways, and 3! in numerator with only Rebecca-Elise fixed and other 3 people matched in 3*2*1 ways

Comment: @MishaLavrov Can y ou maybe provide the approach of solving this? I am completely new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The probability that Rebecca will be chosen is $P_1=\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$.

The probability that Elise will be chosen is $P_2=\frac{4}{9}$.

The probability that they both will be chosen is $P_1\times P_2=\frac{2}{9}$.

In case they both are chosen, they will have $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to be paired. So, the answer of (a) is $\frac{2}{9}\times \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{18}$.

(b) In case they both are chosen, they will have $\frac{3}{4}$ chance ***NOT*** be paired. So, the answer of (b) is $\frac{2}{9}\times \frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{6}$.

(c) The probability that either Rebecca or Elise will be chosen is

$1-(1-P_1)\times(1-P_2)=1-\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{5}{9}=\frac{13}{18}$.

Comment: I am not aware why you're multiplying. Is it because of independent events and stuff? and how did you get 1/4 for both being chosen? Can you provide the solution based on basic counting and not other types? Thank you

Comment: @Roy I didn't say anything about "get 1/4 for both being chosen". Instead, I said (in the third line of my above answer) "The probability that they both will be chosen is $P1×P2=\frac{2}{9}$". Yes, the multiplication used here is because whether Rebecca is chosen is independent of whether Elise is chosen. Only basic concept and basic method of probability theory are used here, and nothing new or strange.

Comment: @Roy  In the fourth line of my answer, I said "In case they both are chosen, they will have $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to be paired." This is because Elise's team has 4 players, among these 4 players only one (i.e. Elise) is to be paired to Rebecca (or Elise).

Comment: I didn't understand the 1/4 part. Can you elaborate a bit further how it's happening?

Comment: @Roy  When you replied to madfdadfd 3 hours ago, you said "@madfdadfd Since they had to be paired. 4! cause both groups can be matched in 4*3*2*1 ways, and 3! in numerator with only Rebecca-Elise fixed and other 3 people matched in 3*2*1 ways ". This is equivalent to say that Rebecca and Elise have a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ to be paired, since $\frac{3!}{4!}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. I didn't realise those steps in between. Thank you!